# spring mvc project not displaying home page after making changes to configuration files(root.xml,servlet-context.xml)

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

***HI all,
I am doing java project using spring mvc in STS(spring tool suite).
when I first created spring mvc project from existing template and ran it, it displayed home page like intended. but, after adding few classes to my project( dao classes, service classes, and few controller classes and few view files(.jsp files)) and changed **root.xml** as follows***

**
    
        
    </context:component-scan>  -->

```
 <bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jobportal_db" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="pswd" />
</bean>**
```

*and **servlet-context.xml** as follow:*

```
<!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

<!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</beans:bean>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.practice.jobportal.controller" />
```

its not displaying home page anymore, instead giving me 
HTTP Status 404 - /jobportal/ as output.

Comment: how is the home page handled? do you have an `index.html` file set as welcome page? or do are you sending `.jsp` from controller response where a request mapping method handles requests to `\`?

Comment: hi, i am sending .jsp file name(ex: home) from controller, where it is mapped to (ex: home.jsp) by view resolver in servlet-context.xml and then render to user.

Comment: can you verify if your startup log is showing the endpoint `/` is registered by spring. also try accessing the url <ip>:<port> without the `/jobportal `

Comment: hey, thanks for the suggestion, actually the problem was caused by pom.xml file. I didn't match the name filed in pom file properly with artifact id field in pom.xml.

Comment: is this a new project? then if you can, you should develop it using spring boot, or at least get rid of all xml config and do java config. just a suggestion..